# how to definitively remove cardview's border android

Tags: android

I have an issue with my cardview. I have an undesired white border as you can see on this:

[Undesired white border image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnsXs.png)

How can I remove  that ?

My codes:

Cardiew background xml in drawable

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp"> 
<solid android:color="@color/text_color_grey_dark"/> 
    <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

Component cardview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/card_view_item"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_extra_extra_short"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_extra_short"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_extra_short"
card_view:cardElevation="0dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout_transfer_history_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_standard">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_image"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_image"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_standard"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/person_photo"

        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_image"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_image"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_standard"
        android:src="@drawable/unknown"

        app:shadow="false" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/person_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/person_transfert_type"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="sample"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/margin_standard" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/person_amount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/person_name"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
                android:text="€ 112"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/person_transfert_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/person_name"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_amount"
                android:text="  \\ 03.12.12"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/person_transfert_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="SENT"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `preventCornerOverlap`, according to documentation:

> On API 20 and before, CardView does not clip the bounds of the Card for the rounded corners. Instead, it adds padding to content so that it won't overlap with the rounded corners. You can disable this behavior by setting this field to false.
>
> Setting this value on API 21 and above does not have any effect unless you have enabled compatibility padding.